# POSIX Shell Script throws syntax error with ./configure

Tags: autoconf

I'm about done working out the dependencies for compiling a program on my linux box.  I'm running Linux Mint 19 64bit.  The last hurdle I can't seem to get over is a syntax error about a specific line in the configure shell script.  Exact error is:

./configure: line 1804: syntax error near unexpected token `[foreign]'
./configure: line 1804:`AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])'

The sister file configure.ac has a reference to AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign]), and if I remove the offending token of [foreign] many other errors come up.  So the token in some way seems necessary.

The furthest I have been able to get is leaving the contents of the parentheses empty with a single whitespace character, so it would read: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE( ).  This satisfies the errors but moves the syntax error down a line to: ac_ext=c.

Here is the offending section of code.

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])
ac_ext=c
```

This is only two lines in a 2000+ line file.

The shell environment is #! /bin/sh

I've tried changing the environment to bash for the sake of being thorough, but it doesn't make a difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The d0_blind_id package (https://gitlab.com/xonotic/d0_blind_id) contains a script called `autogen.sh`.  Run this script (which calls `autoreconf -i`) to create `configure`.  Run `configure` and then `make`.

The `configure` script should not contain `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` that is part of `configure.ac` which is used by autotools to generate the `configure` script.

When I follow these steps I do not get any errors when running the `configure` script and it does not contain `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE`.

I do not know reason you are getting an error as I can not duplicate the issue.

Comment: Thanks Fred!! This worked like a charm for me.  I appreciate the assistance.